# How to properly set status code for HTTPContext

Tags: iis-7, webforms, vb.net-2010

I am working with webforms and as such I have a website running on IIS 8 on a server 2012, using vb.net.  We have some URL redirection happening on Global.asax, on the Application_BeginRequest event which opens an XML file and compares the incoming request to what it would be translated to in the XML.  If the request cannot be satisfied by searching the XML, then we need to first raise a 410 status code, then redirect to a generic page.  So, the way I've been trying to do this is

```
   HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Raise410", "true")
   HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Redirect", "/" + dv(0)("folder"))
   Throw New HttpException(410, "Gone")
```

Then on the exception catch I do this:

```
     Catch ex As Exception
        If HttpContext.Current.Items("Raise410") IsNot Nothing Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 410
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Items("Redirect"))
        End If
    End Try
```

However all I am getting is a 302 redirect and the 410 is never raised.  I am not sure why and I've tried to figure this out for several hours to no avail.

Comment: This isn't ever possible! Redirect is also a status in HTTP. I mean: you return a 410 response or a 301.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some design flaw in your approach. Both 410 *Gone* and 301 *Redirect* are HTTP status codes.

You can't return a response and then redirect from server code.

One possible approach is returning HTTP/410 from the server side and do the redirect in the client-side using [META refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) or using a `setTimeout` and setting `window.location` to the URL where you want to redirect:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = "http://";
}, 6000); // 6 seconds and do the redirect
```

Comment: I see.  So do I need to create a 410 custom page? or some form of 410 handler in web.config that responds with the appropriate 410 page that contains the redirect?

Comment: @AjaxNgnurse Yeah, a custom ASPX page should be enough, so you can inject there the JavaScript or META refresh to do the whole redirect in the client-side.

Comment: I'll go try that right now.  Thanks!!!.  I was under the impression from the Microsoft Examples that whenever you set a StatusCode in the response, it would be somehow "queued" and sent synchronously back to the client somehow.  But now it is clear to me that's not the case, and there is only one response code sent for the entire round trip of the request.

Comment: @AjaxNgnurse Yeah, absolutely! There's a single HTTP response and there's no streaming behind the scenes. I mean, once browser has received the response, both client and server end their communication, so there's no chance to say 1 minute later HEYYY I've changed my mind, it was a 301 instead of 410 haha ;)

Comment: I got my 410 finally.  A bit complicated because we are using URL redirection.  Thanks a bunch :)